# If statement in Ruby using Regex

Tags: ruby

Everything seems to be working fine except the commented line:

```
#return false if not s[0].upcase =~ /AZ/
```

and the fourth check.

What is the correct `if` statement for `s[0]` and `/AZ/` comparison?

```
def starts_with_consonant?(s)
   return false if s.length == 0
   #return false if not s[0].upcase =~ /AZ/
   n = "AEIOU"
   m = s[0]
   return true if not n.include? m.upcase
   false
 end

 puts starts_with_consonant?("Artyom") # false 1
 puts starts_with_consonant?("rtyom")  # true 2
 puts starts_with_consonant?("artyom") # false 3
 puts starts_with_consonant?("$rtyom") # false 4
 puts starts_with_consonant?("") # false 5
```

Comment: It returns all checks as false then, been there, done so...

Comment: So, I answer to my own question - it should be `return false if s[0].upcase.match(/\W/)`

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, you should put it in an answer as opposed to a comment. However, your answer is incorrect as it doesn't distinguish vowels from consonants.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```rb
def starts_with_consonant? s
  /^[^aeiou\d\W]/i =~ s ? true : false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with regex:

```
def starts_with_consonant?(s)
   !!(s =~  /^[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/i)
end
```

This matches the first character of the string with the set of consonants. The `!!` forces the output to true/false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure what your regex is trying to achieve, so I can't suggest a fix. But for the entire method, I'd keep it simple by using the [=== operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) and making the regex case-insensitive with the `i` option:

```
def starts_with_consonant?(s)
    /^[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/i === s
end
```

Comment: `!!s[/^[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/i]` is equivalent.

Comment: Yes @theTinMan, equivalent, but in my opinion, more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

This works too

```
    def starts_with_consonant? s
      return /^[^aeiou]/i === s
    end
```