# Regex for words and spaces?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to match words and spaces:

```
"Hello There" - Match
"#Hello" - No Match
"123Hello" - No Match
```

It should something like this:

```
( *[a-zA-Z]* *)
```

I need to define a method `starts_with_consonant?(s)` that takes a string and returns true if it starts with a consonant and false otherwise.

For our purposes, a consonant is any letter other than 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'.

This is for a course.

Comment: Why don't you try? Also, could you provide a bit more informationon what do you want to achieve?

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/x5soHBbt1n  does this mean it will match or not I cant tell because sometimes it will say no match but others it shows up and highlights some so if i put #Hello in would it match it all? Im at school right now or i would just try it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You started out indicating you want to match words and spaces. Your example shows you want to match something with a space. And your final request indicates you want to match something that starts with a consonant. Could you please clarify?

Comment: So you are actually sitting in an exam hall?

Comment: We don't take orders from you.

Comment: I just want the regex thats just the question im using it in

Comment: There's a nice Ruby library for working with regular expressions if you're kind of new to them. It's called [regularity](https://github.com/andrewberls/regularity) - *Regularity is a friendly regular expression builder for Ruby*.

Comment: Interesting how this question is so similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/19214270/128421.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
(?<=^|\s)[a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*(?=\s|$)
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/qoPJ105gLm) of this working with your examples (and others)

---

If you want to match only if the *whole* input matches, swap the look arounds for `^` and `$`:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/uVkqLlekKZ) of this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this does almost what you want:

```
\A(\w*\s+\w+)+\Z
```